# How to load Material UI Theme based on Redux Store entry

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the below file as the first file that loads when my application loads. I want to pull the palette type from my Redux store like `this.props.pageTheme` so when I trigger a change to the theme, it takes place in the whole app. though when I enter `type: this.props.pageTheme` I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.. Which would make sense because store is not generated by the time const kicks in. But .. Then, how can I read what's in the store and change on the page? I've seen solutions like creating multiple theme const and applying that based on `this.props.getTheme` within return of the app but that's so ugly way of doing it. Is there any smart way to handle theme value injection into the createMuiTheme?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <>page content</>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pageTheme: state.Page.Theme
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: Like you can check whether this.props is not undefined then try to get the theme using this.props.pageTheme. Have a default value in the redux Initial store. And when the action fires anyway there will be a reducer to update this state in the store and the component will re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am sure there will be people looking for an answer for this issue since it's sleek to offer users an ability to change the color mode of your app. My solution is below, if I come across any, I will update it.

In Redux Store I have:

```
const initialState = {
  Page: {
    Theme: "light"
  },
};
```

In main App.js file I have

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme(this.props.pageTheme)}>
```

as a wrapper around the content that I have on the page.

and I have the below function for theme

```
function theme(mode) {
  return createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: mode,
      primary: {
        light: "#757ce8",
        main: "#3f50b5",
        dark: "#002884",
        contrastText: "#fff"
      },
      secondary: {
        light: "#ff7961",
        main: "#f44336",
        dark: "#ba000d",
        contrastText: "#000"
      }
    }
  });
}
```

If you have any suggestions over this to get it better, still highly appreciated.